# Show buttons on a partial view based on some query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am showing search results same as searching groups on facebook
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4jiA.jpg)

I have a relationship Table named **CommunityUser** in Database having attributes **CommunityID** and **UserID**.

Using Partial View I want to show if User not already joined that Community/Group that it will show **Join Button** else if user already joined that community it will show **Leave** button.

I have written IsMember() function in my controller that takes two parameters, **CommunityID** and **UserID**. This will return true if that Community ID exist against that user ID.

```
        public bool IsMember(string UserID, int CommunityID) {

        var Membership = db.Users.Include(x => x.CommunityUsers).Where(s => s.Id.Equals(UserID)).Count();

        if(Membership>0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;

    }
```

Now what I actually need is, I want to call this function in an IF condition on my view class. It is not allowing me to call this function on my view Class.

```
@if (){

<button>@Html.ActionLink("Leave", "LeaveCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>

}
else
{
<button>@Html.ActionLink("Join", "joinCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>

}
```

Comment: Is your action method is json return type ? Any error are you getting after click ??

Comment: this is my all code.? Can I do it without JSON or how can I do it with JSON?

Comment: I can't see LeaveCommunity or JoinCommunity Action method. Add that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you should have a method which will return this view. So in this method you call this function

```
public ActionResult Index(string UserID, int CommunityID)
{
    var hasMembership = IsMember(serID, CommunityID);
    return View(hasMembership);
}
```

In the View it self then you just grab this variable `hasMembership` you just passed from `@model`.

```
@if (Model){
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Leave", "LeaveCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>
}
else
{
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Join", "joinCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>
}
```

**Note:** it might be wise to create some DTO class for passing data to a view, because you might need to pass multiple value to a view at some point. Plus the whole condition would be more readable

```
public SomeDTO {
    public bool IsMember {get;set}
    public List<Community> Communities {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Index(string UserID, int CommunityID)
{
    var hasMembership = IsMember(serID, CommunityID);
    var listOfCommunities = _repo.GetComunities();

    var dto = new SomeDTO
    {
        IsMember = hasMembership,
        Communities = listOfCommunities
    }
    return View(dto);
}

@if (Model.IsMember){
    // do or do not something
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is a good idea to take IsMember().List from the controller but I'm already passing a search Community List from Controller. Can you please elaborate how can I pass IsMember().List with my existing SearchCommunity().List

Comment: edited answer. So now you just have a DTO class, where you add both list of communities and hasMembership boolean. And in a view you just go `@Model.Communities `